# SVD in R recomposition

Tags: r, svd

```
A<-matrix(c(1,1,1,2,0,0,0,1,2,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,2,2,1,1,0,0,0, 
0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,1,1), nrow=5,byrow = TRUE)
svd<-svd(A)
U<-svd$u
V<-svd$v
d<-svd$d

U%*%d%*%t(V)
```

Fairly basic question. By the definition of SVD, this matrix should recompose, but it doesn't. I'm clearly making a very stupid mistake here, but I don't understand where this function varies from the definition of SVD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

d are the singular values of M. you need to place d in a diagonal matrix:

[image]

```
U%*%diag(d) %*% t(V)
```

Comment: Ah yes it was something really stupid. Thank you.